# Script won't check if submit button is clicked in php

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, post, submit

I would like to check if a submit button is clicked. I thought I did it the right way, but it doesnt work. I'm using twitterBootstrap for all the styling.

form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="control/checkCall.php">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputUser" name="username">Gebruikersnaam</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputUser" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword" name="userpass">Wachtwoord</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> Onthouden
      </label>
      <button type="submit" name="submitLogin" class="btn">Inloggen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

checkCall.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])){
        echo 'hoi';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpass = md5($_POST['userpass']);
        checkLogin($username,$userpass);            
    }
```

Url that comes out of clicking the submit button
http://inspired.xeption.nl/bootstrap/control/checkCall.php?submitLogin=

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden input field in the form, with a static value. Then you check for that input field. But then again, why not just check if another input field is there?

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {...}
```

Right now, you check for a field that is not even in the form, you know.